# What are static vs dynamic labels in Grafana Loki?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

The Loki documentation states the following:

> Try to keep values bounded to as small a set as possible. We don’t have perfect guidance as to what Loki can handle, but think single digits, or maybe 10’s of values for a dynamic label. This is less critical for static labels. For example, if you have 1,000 hosts in your environment it’s going to be just fine to have a host label with 1,000 values.

From my understanding, each combination of labels in Loki will create a new stream. So `request=GET,host=my-host-1` will write to a different file than `request=POST,host=my-host-1`.

But what is a dynamic vs a static label? Searching "loki static vs dynamic labels" does not yield useful results.

My best guess is--if we describe labels as key, value pairs--then static labels are ones where the key is fixed but the value can be anything & dynamic labels are ones where both the key & value can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only fundamental difference between static and dynamic labels is that, it's common to have unbounded or infinite label values for the second one. This uncontrolled fact can lead to a big issue for Loki. If you have a limited and controlled number of values, dynamic labels are not worst than static labels. Anyway, always have in mind the following rule: "don’t add a label for something until you know you need it!".

You can find a lot of valuable info at:

[How labels in Loki can make log queries faster and easier](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/04/21/how-labels-in-loki-can-make-log-queries-faster-and-easier/)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm confused because the docs say that 1K different values for a static label are fine, but we should have @ most 10's of different values for a dynamic label; this seems to indicate a deeper difference?

Comment: I understand, I really can't see any difference between them other than the unpredictability issue.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding (it is not 100% clear in the documentation)

**Static labels** as shown in the installation guide are compiled with the environment ( application, os, container name etc)

**Dynamic labels** are added at run-time (user-id, event-type etc) and that is why they should be used with caution as the key/values are potentially infinite.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one type of label!

The distinction is on the usage. If the label has a finite number of values then it's called **static** and if the possibilities are endless it's called **dynamic**.

Don't overuse labels, use them only when they are absolutely critical such as the application and the environment. Check [Prometheus don't overuse labels](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/instrumentation/#do-not-overuse-labels), they have the same philosophy with Loki.

Never use labels on something that could have unpredictable number of values (such as user_id or Request IP).

Check the [Loki best practices for labels](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/get-started/labels/bp-labels/)

Comment: Why not? _ignore 6 extra chars_

Comment: @Kashyap I am nor sure I understand your question, why not what? Not to overuse the labels or not using the labels on a userId? Loki is creating a sequence for every label combination, it's not efficient to have a million sequences with just a few logs in it.

Comment: Last two sentences in your post: _"Don't overuse labels, use them only when they are absolutely critical such as the application and the environment."_ AND _"Never use labels on something that could have unpredictable number of values (such as user_id or Request IP)."_ E.g. I would like to have a `correlation_id` added to all my logs associated with one request as it goes across 4 different lambda functions (micros services). So my search to get all logs related to a single request is simple `correlation_id=12345`. There would be millions of `correlation_id`.

Comment: @Kashyap Include the information at the message and use the 'Line contains' search, such as `{application="YourApp"} |= \`correlation_id=12345\``. This will bring all the rows that contains such data.

Comment: To be blunt: You're telling everyone what to do and what not to do. Can you explain WHY?

Comment: @Kashyap Please check the updated answer, and read article linked.